# Google Map Circle not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can't Draw Circle in Google Map

I am following this tutorial by google :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

I can't find what is the mistake i am doing.

**Here is my Google Map API Code :**

```
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
<?php
$lat = '11.0183';
$lng = '76.9725';
?>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $lat ;?>", <?php echo $lng ;?>),
          population: 14856,
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      var citymap = {};
citymap['userplace'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $lat ;?>", <?php echo $lng ;?>),
  population: 14856
};

var cityCircle;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
  };

    </script>

  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
```

I just want to draw circle in the Map that i have Loaded.

How can i fix this ??

Comment: why `android` tag ..its php and java script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the quotes on the `phpcode` just use like this otherwise it takes the value as string.

```
var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat ;?>, <?php echo $lng ;?>),
          population: 14856,
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
```

Comment: Though it doesn't helps me , i am accepting the answer. Kindly upvote if my question was ok

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually creating a circle.  Look at the example again, you removed this line:

```
// Add the circle for this city to the map.
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
```

from the loop. Should be like this:

```
for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
}
```

Working snippet:

```js
$lat = '11.0183';
$lng = '76.9725';

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng($lat, $lng),
    population: 14856,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  var cityCircle;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var citymap = {};
citymap['userplace'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng($lat, $lng),
  population: 14856
};
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```